# Multiple async/await event loop order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I got my head spinning off while learn asynchronous javascript.
I have following code in async function:

```
const promise1 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
  });
};
const promise2 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
};
await promise1();
console.log(1);
await promise2();
console.log(2);
```

It's work as i expect: "Wait for 3 seconds,do something synchronous,then wait 1 seconds and do something also synchronous".
But if i change my both constants from anonymous function expression to Promise constructor

```
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
});
const promise4 = new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
});
```

and call it as

```
await promise3;
console.log(3);
await promise4;
console.log(4);
```

my logic fails - second console.log(3) execute immediatelly without 1 second delay.

But again, if i return to first code and change timeout delay so that first delay will be less than second (i.e. first timeout delay 2000ms and second will be 3000) - second console.log(2) execute after difference time between 3000-2000=1000ms.

Can someone detailed explain how it works?
I figure out,that's all about micro and macrotask in event loop, but don't understand, why i got this result.

P.S. I know, that both await can be replaced by:

```
delay(ms1)
.tnen(() =>{
  console.log('some1');
  return delay(ms2);
})
.then(() =>{
  console.log('some2')
})
```

Just need to understand deep mechanism of event loop with async\await;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I figure out,that's all about micro and macrotask in event loop...

Not really. The key thing is that the `Promise` constructor calls the function you pass it (the promise executor function) **immediately** and **synchronously**. So the timer starts when you do `new Promise`, not later when you use `await`, so you're starting both timers one right after the other. In contrast, your first code block doesn't call `new Promise` to start the second timer until *after* the first timer has fired, because you're awaiting the first result before calling `promise2()` to get the promise for the second timer (which is what starts it).

Let's see that in action by adding some logging (I've changed `promise1` to `function` and `promise2` to `function2`, since they aren't promises, they're functions):

```js
(async () => {
    const start = Date.now();
    const log = (...msgs) => console.log(String(Date.now() - start).padStart(4, "0"), ...msgs);

    const function1 = () => {
        log("function1 called");
        return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
            log("starting 3000ms timer");
            setTimeout(() => {
                log("fulfilling 3000ms timer");
                resolve();
            }, 3000);
        });
    };
    const function2 = () => {
        log("function1 called");
        return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
            log("starting 1000ms timer");
            setTimeout(() => {
                log("fulfilling 1000ms timer");
                resolve();
            }, 1000);
        });
    };
    log("Calling and waiting on function1");
    await function1();
    log(1);
    log("Calling and waiting on function2");
    await function2();
    log(2);

    log("Creating promise3");
    const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        log("starting 3000ms timer");
        setTimeout(() => {
            log("fulfilling 3000ms timer");
            resolve();
        }, 3000);
    });
    log("Creating promise4");
    const promise4 = new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        log("starting 1000ms timer");
        setTimeout(() => {
            log("fulfilling 1000ms timer");
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
    log("Waiting for promise3");
    await promise3;
    log(3);
    log("Waiting for promise4");
    await promise4;
    log(4);
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

With that, we get output something like this:

```
0000 Calling and waiting on function1
0001 function1 called
0001 starting 3000ms timer
3003 fulfilling 3000ms timer
3004 1
3006 Calling and waiting on function2
3008 function1 called
3009 starting 1000ms timer
4011 fulfilling 1000ms timer
4012 2
4014 Creating promise3
4016 starting 3000ms timer
4017 Creating promise4
4019 starting 1000ms timer
4020 Waiting for promise3
5020 fulfilling 1000ms timer
7018 fulfilling 3000ms timer
7019 3
7021 Waiting for promise4
7023 4
```

Notice how `promise3` and `promise4` both start their timers right away, overlapping them.